# Yii gridview change cell background color

Tags: css, gridview, yii, cell, background-color

I would like to change background color in a (bootstrap) grid in yii, depending on compared cell values.
It took me a while to figure out where do I even have to place CSS class to get something - .../protected/css/styles.css:

```
.notice {
    background:#FFF6BF;
    color:#514721;
}
```

I hope this is the right place.
In my grid:

```
'columns' => array(
    ...
    array(
        'name' => 'Pcs',
        'cssClassExpression' => '$data["Pcs"] <> $data["Pcs"] ? "notice" : ""',
    ),
```

this way, my css definition is applied only in every second row. I've read a lot about this in different topics: [CGridView. Add custom class to table rows preserving original „odd“ and „even“](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/501/cgridview-add-custom-class-to-table-rows-preserving-original-odd-and-even/) and also here in stackoverflow.com.
I know there are "odd" and "even" rows, but I still don't get the picture. I've tried to manually change rowCssClassExpression

```
'rowCssClassExpression' => '',
```

because I thought if I disable basic yii row coloring, my css will apply, and in html source I can see there are proper class definitions for each row, but still, rows background color remained the same. What should I do to make it work?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css rules are being ignored. The selector that's being applied is `table tr td` thus yours should be as follows

```
table tr td.notice {
    background:#FFF6BF;
    color:#514721;
}
```

If this doesn't work you could always set the rules using `!important`